# What is the difference btw Title and Name in IAM roles in Google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am getting confused between Title and Names when i have to choose Names and when i have to choose Title. There is a role of Compute Viewer in IAM Roles. I can search it in filter by title `(Title:Compute Viewer)` but not able to filter it with Name by `Name:roles/Compute Viewer.`
i am able to filter Compute Viewer role via Title

[image: how i am able to filter via Title]

but i am not able to filter compute viewer role by using name
[image: i am not able to filter compute viewer role by using name]

Comment: do you want to filter the IAM role? Do you want to use them? Can you clarify your use and your blocker?

Comment: Yes i want to filter the IAM role. there are many parameters available like Title Name. So i am confused in between Title and Name

Comment: Can you share how do you query the roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you filter on a role, you cannot filter by "**ID**" but you can filter by "Name"; these two terms seem to be used interchangeably in many places. Role IDs must be unique within the project or organization in which you created the role. This ensures that the role's full ID, which includes its project or organization, is unique.

The role **title** appears in the list of roles in the Cloud console. Consider indicating in the role title if the role is an organization-level role or a project-level role. Role titles can be up to 100 bytes long and can contain uppercase and lowercase alphanumeric characters and symbols. You can change role titles at any time.

To filter the role of Compute Viewer in IAM Roles using the **title** use `Title:Compute Viewer` and to filter the role of Compute Viewer in IAM Roles using **name** use `Name:roles/compute.viewer`. In your use case, you are not able to filter compute viewer role by using name because you are using the wrong filter which is `Name:roles/Compute Viewer` , try changing the filter to `Name:roles/compute.viewer` as mentioned in the screenshot.

[image]

Refer [Predefined compute engine roles](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.viewer) and [naming the role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles#naming_the_role) for more information.

Comment: Okay but why we use dot in between compute viewer role in Name but not use dot in Title

Comment: This is the built-in format that is being followed to specify Title and Name. Also if the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for community members.

Comment: Yes i have marked it